# Authenticate employee in module front controller ajax actions

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

In Prestashop 1.5 I need to grant the permission to execute some ajax actions in module front controller only to employee.

```
Context::getContext()->employee
```

is only available in admin context, so in module front controllers is always null.

How I should autenticate an employee in module front controllers context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the previous versions of PrestaShop you could use Cookie->isLoggedBack() however this method is now deprecated (moved to Employee->isLoggedBack() which works only in the Admin Panel).

A proper way of checking if an employee is logged to the Admin Panel whether you are in a front-end or back-end controller can now be:

```
$cookie = new Cookie('psAdmin', '', (int)Configuration::get('PS_COOKIE_LIFETIME_BO'));
$employee = new Employee((int)$cookie->id_employee);

if (Validate::isLoadedObject($employee) && $employee->checkPassword((int)$cookie->id_employee, $cookie->passwd)
&& (!isset($cookie->remote_addr) || $cookie->remote_addr == ip2long(Tools::getRemoteAddr()) || !Configuration::get('PS_COOKIE_CHECKIP')))
        die('Logged In, Your code here');
    else
        die('User is not logged in');
```

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->employee->id = 1;
```

Comment: As I said, employee is available only in admin context (admincontroller or moduleadmincontroller), and I'm in a module front controller. So employee is always null.